# How do I submit a form in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue with the submission of the information from this form I created with Node.js. Can someone please help me? I'm receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'conteudo')
```

my code

```js
const express=require("express");
const app=express();
const handlebars=require("express-handlebars");
const Sequelize=require("sequelize");


const sequelize=new Sequelize("test","root","88182231",{
    host:"localhost",
    dialect:"mysql"
})

app.get("/card",function(req,res){
    res.render("form")
})

app.post("/add",function(req,res){
     res.send("conteudo:"+req.body.conteudo+" titulo:"+req.body.titulo)
})

app.engine("handlebars", handlebars.engine({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine","handlebars");
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(express.json())
```

I have already tried changing my database, even the data type from TEXT to STRING, and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `express.json()` middleware. It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and you can access the passed data using req.body.

Learn more: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

so add `app.use(express.json())` somewhere after `const app=express();`;

Answer (score 0):

it needs reorder codes

```
const express=require("express");
const app=express();
const handlebars=require("express- 
handlebars");
const Sequelize=require("sequelize");

 app.engine("handlebars", handlebars.engine({ 
 defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine","handlebars");
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(express.json())

const sequelize=new 
Sequelize("test","root","88182231",{
host:"localhost",
dialect:"MySQL"
 })

 app.get("/card",function(req,res){
 res.render("form")
   })

app.post("/add",function(req,res){
  res.send("conteudo:"+req.body.conteudo+" 
titulo:"+req.body.titulo)
})
```